# href link not working in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

href link not working in Asp.Net windows form. I have explained every thing in images. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[image: Main Code section]

[image: error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: ASP.Net and WinForms have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: Compare the URL to the actual path to the file.  Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: What you mean #SLaks ?

Comment: so many bad tags... no mvc, no bootstrap, not asp classic, don't know how html5 is relevant

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the MVC pattern (dispite your tag). Try

```
<a href="/Front/admin_login.aspx">
```